# Getting internet permission in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-manifest

I'm new to flutter and I'm in a situation to get internet permission for our flutter app which we are developing, we've used [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-) for handling permissions. We also accessed microphone permission and it worked well. but can't get the internet permission request.

And I want to know whether internet permission(But I've mentioned in the Manifest.xml file) is not mandatory or not?

Comment: just write <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your anrdoidmanifest.xml file :)

Comment: @ParthPitroda, hey I know it's late to say a huge thanks for your comment,but ya,have a great day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACCESS\_NETWORK\_STATE permission on Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778168/access-network-state-permission-on-android-ics)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just write this in your Anroidmanifest.xml in android module in flutter project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: What to do in iOS ?

Comment: for ios as far as IK there is no need :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430142/is-there-an-internet-permission-in-ios

Answer (score 15):

Internet permissions are required for macOS in addition to Android so I'm adding an expanded answer.

### Android

Add the following line in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file before the `<application>` section:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

See also the [Flutter docs for creating an Android release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest).

### macOS

Add the following key-value pair to **macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements** and **macos/Runner/Release.entitlements**:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

See also the [Desktop support for Flutter](https://flutter.dev/desktop#setting-up-entitlements) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a better solution . Paste the code below to android manifest.xml

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" / 

uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Comment: Please don't copy other's answers. Instead flag for duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458189/5468463

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click info.plist and Open As -> Source Code. This will open the file in XML format.

- Add the following to the bottom of the info.plist xml file.

  ```
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
  ```